# How to put a PC into sleep mode using python?

Tags: python

While the copy is in progress, can we put a PC into sleep mode for a specific period of time, then wake up and continue copy using python script? Can you please share the code?

Actually this is possible using shell script.

Comment: why are you doing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Most machines manufactured after 2000 support real-time clock wakeup.  There are many reasons to do so, one of which would be to record a TV program at a certain time.  See [ACPI Wakeup](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/ACPI_Wakeup).

You'll have to explain what you mean by "While the copy is in progress" - there's not much to go on in the question.  While OS drivers have suspend/resume functions, I don't know how to tell the python interpreter to save its state in the middle of running a script and then resume after wakeup.  It's possible that the OS suspend/hibernate would fully capture the state of a copy operation and resume without a hiccup, but I wouldn't trust it to do so without substantial testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Wake On Lan" enabled you could potentially run a python script on a different PC and trigger the wake up after your specific period of time.

The scripts would probably need to talk to each other, unless you just do it all at times set in advance.